# Click.Argument does not throw Error for missing argument

Tags: python, arguments, click, command-line-interface

I have a CLI tool and I have `click.argument` in one of the command.

Initially, I had this:

```
@click.argument(
    'file',
    type=click.Path(exists=True),
)
```

If I didn't add the `file` argument in the command, It used to throw error like this:

```
Error: Missing argument 'FILE'.
```

Now, I added the possibility of having unlimited number of arguments by adding `nargs=-1` like this:

```
@click.argument(
    'file',
    nargs=-1,
    type=click.Path(exists=True),
)
```

Now, if I don't pass the `file` argument, I don't get the error message as above.

What I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've established your argument can accept an unlimited number of inputs, you also accept the possibility of no inputs.

Per the documentation of [Variadic Functions](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/arguments/#variadic-arguments), the values are passed as a tuple. You are likely receiving an empty tuple which will not cause an error.

A little further down in the docs, there is a section about **Non-Empty Variadic Arguments**. This is a supported feature by using `required=True`, however, not recommend. A quote from the docs:

> The reason for this is that very often, scripts are invoked with wildcard inputs from the command line and they should not error out if the wildcard is empty.

In any case, below is a snippet that should fix your issue.

```
@click.argument(
    'file',
    nargs=-1,
    type=click.Path(exists=True),
    required=True
)
```